# create link to open app for mobile on URL for desktops

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, onclick, deep-linking

I need to make a link open the native social media app if installed or redirect to the URL if not installed or if user is on a desktop.

I am using this bit of code in my link.

```
<a href="fb://MY FB PAGE" onclick="setTimeout(function(){ window.location='https://www.MY FB PAGE' }, 100)"></a>
```

It works great except with desktops.  The URL actually loads just fine, but, there is an error pop up stating that it can't open up the 'fb://'.  Which makes sense, but like I said, this error pop up is not preventing the URL from loading,  my facebook page shows up, just has the pop up window over the top and once I click 'do nothing' it goes away and all is good.

How can I make that error window not pop up on desktops?

I have tried a lot of different javascript functions to try and make the app open in mobile and URL in desktop.  Many of them came from here.  But none of them have worked for me.  My code is the only thing that has come close to doing what I want.

I am looking for a proven code to accomplish this task or modification of my code above.

Comment: how about making two links (mobile and desktop) then using a media query to hide one or the other depending on screen size?

Answer (score 0):

Make two links (mobile and desktop) then use a media query to hide one or the other depending on screen size. see example https://jsfiddle.net/kh0prtc4/9/

html

```
<a class="mobile" href="fb://MY FB PAGE" onclick="setTimeout(function(){ window.location='https://www.MY FB PAGE' }, 100)">mobile</a>
<a class="desktop" href="MY FB PAGE" onclick="setTimeout(function(){ window.location='https://www.MY FB PAGE' }, 100)">desktop</a>
```

css

```
.mobile {
  display: none;
}

    @media (max-width: 600px) {
      .desktop {
        display: none;
      }
      .mobile {
        display: inline;
      }
    }
```

Comment: This isn't a bad idea.  But my site is responsive so if the user resizes their screen below the colapae point on a desktop it will call the mobile media query and I'll run into the same problem.  I realize that the odds of users actually doing this is rare but it still might happen so I would rather figure out how to do it without media queries.

Comment: true, however when you are surfing the internet, how often do you minimize the browser to a cellphone size to browse on a desktop? the answer is actually, never. you can "what if" yourself to death when building a responsive website, or you can design it to fit the majority of people.